# jQuery slide tittle stops before end his cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, easing

Slide titles stops not completing the cycle. 
What's missing in code to complete my slide?

```
<div id="overflow-animate">
    <div id="animate-container">
        <h1 class="giga remove-bottom">title1</h1>
        <h1 class="giga remove-bottom">title2</h1>
        <h1 class="giga remove-bottom">title3</h1>
        <h1 class="giga remove-bottom">title4</h1>
        <h1 class="giga remove-bottom">title5</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
//SET DELAY TO MODIFY THE DELAY OF THE INTRO ANIMATION
//INTRO ANIMATION
var delay = 1200;
var titleheight = $('#animate-container h1').outerHeight();
var count = $('#animate-container').height() / titleheight;

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var distance = titleheight * i;
    $('#animate-container').delay(delay).animate({'top': '-' + distance + 'px'}, 400, 'easeOutBounce');
}

$('#animate-container').delay(800).animate({'top': '0px'}, 500, 'easeOutBounce');

if ($(".home .cover i").length > 0 && $(window).width() > 767) {
    $('.home .cover i').delay((count * delay) + (delay * 2)).animate({'top': $('.cover i').offset().top - 180}, 500, 'easeOutBounce', function() {
        //$('.cover h3').fadeIn(500);
    });
}
//END WINDOW ANIMATION
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YH5QV/5/

Comment: Please post the whole code on jsfiddle so it's easier to read it...

Comment: I updated your question, spacing it out some and gave you a jsFiddle to work with. Edit that fiddle to suit the setup and then edit the link here

Comment: Also, it's not clear what your question is. Please take another look and try editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem:

```
var container = $('#animate-container'),
    gigaH1 = container.find('h1'),
    titleHeight = gigaH1.height() + parseInt(gigaH1.css('margin-top'), 10);
(function animateH1() {
    for (var i = 0; i < gigaH1.length; i++) {
        container.delay(1200).animate({
            'top': '-' + titleHeight * i
        }, 400, 'easeOutBounce');
    }
    container.delay(800).animate({ 'top': 0 }, 500, 'easeOutBounce', animateH1);
}());
```

CSS:

```
#animate-container {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    top: 0;
}
#overflow-animate {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 79px;
}
```

First off the code caches some variables (`container`, `gigaH1`) as they aren't going to change every time the function is run. It then calculates the offset required to move each H1 out of view.

The function below is self-invoking and simply runs your original code (with a few minor tweaks). The last animation has the `animateH1()` function itself as a callback so the whole animation is run again once it's complete.

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/wAaeD/